# Hashing to Calculate Frequencies can be improved?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

I'm currently working on building a hash table in order to calculate the frequencies, depending on the running time of the data structure. **O(1)** insertion, **O(n)** worse look up time etc.

I've asked a few people the difference between `std::map` and the hash table and I've received an answer as;

*"`std::map` adds the element as a binary tree thus causes **O(log n)** where with the hash table **you implement** it will be **O(n)**."*

Thus I've decided to implement a hash table using the **array of linked lists (for separate chaining)** structure. In the code below I've assigned two values for the node, one being the **key(the word)** and the other being the **value(frequency)**. It works as; when the first node is added if the **index** is empty it is directly inserted as the first element of linked list with the frequency of **0**. If it is already in the list (which unfortunately takes **O(n)** time to search) increment its frequency by 1. If not found simply add it to the beginning of the list.

I know there are a lot of flows in the implementation thus I would like to ask the experienced people in here, **in order to calculate frequencies efficiently**, how can this implementation be improved?

Code I've written so far;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    string word;
    int frequency;
    Node *next;
};

class linkedList
{
private:
    friend class hashTable;
    Node *firstPtr;
    Node *lastPtr;
    int size;
public:
    linkedList()
    {
        firstPtr=lastPtr=NULL;
        size=0;
    }
    void insert(string word,int frequency)
    {
        Node* newNode=new Node;
        newNode->word=word;
        newNode->frequency=frequency;

        if(firstPtr==NULL)
            firstPtr=lastPtr=newNode;
        else {
            newNode->next=firstPtr;
            firstPtr=newNode;
        }

        size++;
    }
    int sizeOfList()
    {
        return size;
    }
    void print()
    {
        if(firstPtr!=NULL)
        {
            Node *temp=firstPtr;
            while(temp!=NULL)
            {
                cout<<temp->word<<" "<<temp->frequency<<endl;
                temp=temp->next;
            }
        }
        else
            printf("%s","List is empty");
    }
};

class hashTable
{
private:
    linkedList* arr;
    int index,sizeOfTable;
public:
    hashTable(int size) //Forced initalizer
    {
        sizeOfTable=size;
        arr=new linkedList[sizeOfTable];
    }
    int hash(string key)
    {
        int hashVal=0;

        for(int i=0;i<key.length();i++)
            hashVal=37*hashVal+key[i];

        hashVal=hashVal%sizeOfTable;
        if(hashVal<0)
            hashVal+=sizeOfTable;

        return hashVal;
    }
    void insert(string key)
    {
        index=hash(key);
        if(arr[index].sizeOfList()<1)
            arr[index].insert(key, 0);
        else {
            //Search for the index throughout the linked list.
            //If found, increment its value +1
            //else if not found, add the node to the beginning
        }
    }



};
```

Comment: `#include <tr1/unordered_map>` if you are on c++03, `#include <unordered_map` if you are on c++11...

Comment: @dionadar Does 'unordered_map' support collision?

Comment: if you need a multimap instead of a map, consider using `<unordered_multimap` :)

Comment: Array of linked lists? Too slow. Use an array of arrays. And yes, `std::unordered_map` does support collisions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you so much for the illuminating answer. However considering k most frequent words, is 'unordered_map' a reasonable choice? **trie** structure has been proposed before but I think it is too complicated to implement for this type of question.

Comment: @rolandbishop A trie isn’t that complicated to implement, give it a shot. To efficiently access the “k most frequent words” neither a hash table nor a trie is particularly well suited since you need to iterate over the whole structure to find this information. A modified priority queue may be better here. I actually think there’s a specialised data structure for that but I don’t know which.

Comment: @rolandbishop As for as I know that a **priorty queue** is that it is a heap that follows the rule: **a node's children won't be bigger than itself**. How can we actually apply this modification to here?

Comment: @OP Is this question ultimately about how to implement a data structure for this (e.g. how to deal with collisions in a hash), or about what data structure (e.g. hash vs. trie etc.) is best suited and what part of the standard library provides it?

Comment: @jogojapan This question is primarily about **what is the best data structure in order to compute frequencies and listing the K most popular words**. Collision detection and handling is actually not much of a big deal, it was more of a question that I've personally wondered.

Answer (score 0):

Do you care about the worst case? If no, use an `std::unordered_map` (it handles collisions and you don't want a `multimap`) or a trie/critbit tree (depending on the keys, it may be more compact than a hash, which may lead to better caching behavior). If yes, use an `std::set` or a trie.

If you want, e.g., online top-k statistics, keep a priority queue *in addition to* the dictionary. Each dictionary value contains the number of occurrences and whether the word belongs to the queue. The queue duplicates the top-k frequency/word pairs but keyed by frequency. Whenever you scan another word, check whether it's both (1) not already in the queue and (2) more frequent than the least element in the queue. If so, extract the least queue element and insert the one you just scanned.

You can implement your own data structures if you like, but the programmers who work on STL implementations tend to be pretty sharp. I would make sure that's where the bottleneck is first.

Answer (score 0):

1- The complexity time for search in std::map and std::set is O(log(n)). And, the amortize time complexity for std::unordered_map and std::unordered_set is O(n). However, the constant time for hashing could be very large and for small numbers become more than log(n). I always consider this face.

2- if you want to use std::unordered_map, you need to make sure that std::hash is defined for you type. Otherwise you should define it.